# I am unable to transfer funds to the owner of my NFT

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, nft, remix

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Shop is ReentrancyGuard {

    uint itemCount;

    struct Item {
        uint itemId;
        address payable owner;
        address nft;
        uint tokenId;
        uint price;
        uint sale;
        uint ownerNumber;
        uint256 warrantyPeriod;
        uint256 dateOfPurcahse;
    }

    mapping(uint => Item) items;

    function listItem(address _nft, uint _tokenId, uint _price, uint256 _warrantyPeriod) external nonReentrant {
        require(_price > 0,"Price must be greate than zero");
        uint itemId = itemCount;
        _warrantyPeriod = _warrantyPeriod * 1 days;
        items[itemId] = Item(itemId,payable(msg.sender),_nft,_tokenId,_price,1,1,_warrantyPeriod,0);
        itemCount++;
    }

    function purchaseItem(uint _itemId) external payable nonReentrant {
        Item storage item = items[_itemId];
        address payable buyer = payable(msg.sender);
        item.owner.transfer(item.price);
        IERC721(item.nft).approve(buyer,item.tokenId);
        IERC721(item.nft).transferFrom(item.owner, buyer, item.tokenId);
        item.owner = buyer;
        item.sale += 1;
        item.ownerNumber += 1;
        item.dateOfPurcahse = block.timestamp;
    }

}
```

I am storing my nft address and tokenId in the Item struct along with address of the owner. On purchasing the item, the caller of the function transfers price of the item to the owner, the nft is transfered to the buyer and the owner of the item is updated to the buyer. I was running this code on remix and it is throwing this error -

```
transact to Shop.purchaseItem errored: VM error: revert.

    revert
        The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
    Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
```

I made sure that the function and address of the owner were payable and the price of the nft was lower than the balance. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
item.owner.transfer(item.price);
```

You have this line in your code. As far as I know, it should be `msg.value`, not `item.price`. Since your function is payable, there should be a value. `msg.sender` is the buyer; `msg.value` is the price. And you should check it like require (`msg.value==item.price`).